# IIS 7 Still showing old certificate

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssl, iis-7, ssl-certificate

I installed an SSL certificate in my IIS 7 (Windows Server 2008). I deleted the expired certificate but still showing when i access from any browser.

- I deleted the expired certificate.
- I Installed the new certificate.
- I Modified the Bindings from my website
- I restarted the site (Restart from the same panel of "Bindings...").
- I restarted the Virtual Machine where IIS7 is installed.

What else should I do to show the correct certificate? Why my server shows the expired certificate if is uninstalled?.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

In our system we have two Virtual Machines with IIS, i installed the certificate in the other and now it works perfectly.